# Whatsapp Login Failed not- authorized

Tags: c#, whatsapp

I am using [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Whatsapp.NET/) API to connect & send message to Whatsapp. Here is the code.

```
byte[] nextChallenge = null;
WhatsApp wa = new WhatsApp("91999999999", "your password(WART)", "Name", true, true);
wa.OnConnectSuccess += () =>
{
    Response.Write("connect");
    wa.OnLoginSuccess += (phno,data) =>
    {
        wa.SendMessage("to", "msg");
    };

    wa.OnLoginFailed += (data) =>
    {
        Response.Write("login failed "+data);
    };
    wa.Login(nextChallenge);
};
wa.OnConnectFailed+= (ex)=>
{
    Response.Write("connection failed");
}
wa.Connect();
```

I have generated the password with WART, but every time I run the code I get the error message

```
Login Failed not- authorized
```

What wrong I am doing there ?

Comment: Did you resolved this issue?

Comment: No, couldn't find the solution form anywhere till now.

Answer (score 0):

Wart Tool is out-dated now. moreover, whatsapp has removed the concept of password. it uses 2 step verification method now. unfortunately, 2 step verification is in BETA state at the time of writing this post.